# No branch in info bar when running dev containers

Tags: branch, vscode-devcontainer

Up until VSC 1.75.1 when running dev containers the branch name was listed in the info bar (at the bottom of VSC). Any version higher will no longer show this. For now we have downgraded VSC to version 1.75.1 and won't install any updates. It looks like not all extension are loaded anymore when starting dev containers. We don't seen any errors, and downgrading to 1.71.1 does fix this problem.

We tried removing and adding the required extension. Uninstalling VSC and start from scratch. The only thing that seems to work is downgrading to version 1.75.1. That is the highest version that still works.